# Get control upper right corner location

Tags: c#, winforms

I know control.location gives the coordinates of the upper left corner of the control, but I was wondering if there is a method to return the coordinates of the upper right corner, or do I have to do it like (simplified code below):

```
control.location.X + control.size.X //as an example
```

Comment: You are on the right track, in your case I would just add the width of your control to your location.X value.

Comment: Yeah, like I said that is just simplyfied code, since it's a simple question. Thank you for your input, but does that mean there isn't a method to get that location and I have to do it by hand?

Comment: As far as I know. Not by my computer. But check the methods in Control.Bounds property

Comment: Control.Bounds.Right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [`Control.Bounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx) property. It is a [`System.Drawing.Rectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) Structure which has Left, Right, Top and Bottom property's.

Definition of Right is:

> Gets the x-coordinate that is the sum of X and Width property values of this Rectangle structure.

In short it does it for you.